# Cuenta regresiva entre dos fechas con php

Tags: php

Tengo un codigo que muestras la cantidad de dias entre dos fechas, pero ahora le tengo que agregar que `faltan X dias` y cuando se termine me muestre que ya esta `finalizado`. Trate de hacerlo usando `if`, pero no logro tener resultado.

```
<?php
    $fechaInicio = new DateTime('2019-03-10');
    $fechaFinal = new DateTime('2019-03-28');
    $resultado = $fecha1->diff($fechaFinal);

    echo $resultado->format('%a días');  // 18 días 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que esto te puede servir. Aquí se calculan:

- El total de días entre las dos fechas dadas
- Los días que faltan  para que termine (en base a la fecha actual)
- Los días que ya han transcurrido
- Mostrará cuando haya terminado

La clave es crear los objetos con este formato `'!Y-m-d'`, para que no asigne de forma arbitraría la hora, ya que `DateTime` es muy preciso calculando la diferencia de días, si las fechas tienen hora también las tomará en cuenta.

```
$df='!Y-m-d';
$fechaInicio = DateTime::createFromFormat($df,'2019-03-10');
$fechaFinal  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df,'2019-03-28');
$fechaHoy=new DateTime('today');
$totalDays = $fechaInicio->diff($fechaFinal)->d;   #Días totales entre las fechas dadas
$diffDays = $fechaFinal->diff($fechaHoy)->d;       #Días que faltan para que termine
$pastDays = $fechaInicio->diff($fechaHoy)->d;      #Días ya transcurridos
$msgInfo= $fechaFinal == $fechaHoy ? "Terminado": "Faltan $diffDays días. Han transcurrido $pastDays de $totalDays días totales";
echo $msgInfo;
```

**Salida:**

```
Faltan 1 días. Han transcurrido 17 de 18 días totales
```

Comment: Gracias Cedano, funciona bien con los dias a futuro. Pero en el listado general hay tareas que ya fueron realizadas en un periodo de fechas del: `2019-03-10` al `2019-03-18` y el resultados es: `Faltan 8 días. Han transcurrido 16 de 8 días totales` lo cual tendria que decir que esa tarea ya fue finalizada o vencida

Comment: Ah claro, @previant, sólo hay que cambiar la comparación de `==` por esto: `<=` y problema resuelto: **`$msgInfo= $fechaFinal <= $fechaHoy ? "Terminado": "Faltan $diffDays días. Han transcurrido $pastDays de $totalDays días totales";`**

Comment: aaaaaah.... soy un tonto... perdon y gracias nuevamente!

Answer (score 0):

Viendo que el anterior no era lo que esperabas... Aquí tienes uno en PHP:

```
<?php
//fecha fin (sin ceros delante y las horas en formato 24 h)
$hora = 0;
$dia = 28;
$mes = 3;
$ano = 2019;
//fecha inicio (sin ceros delante y las horas en formato 24 h)
$hora2 = 0;
$dia2 = 10;
$mes2 = 3;
$ano2 = 2019;
$fin = mktime($hora,0,0,$mes,$dia,$ano);
$inicio = mktime($hora2,0,0,$mes2,$dia2,$ano2);
$cuenta_atras = floor(($fin - $inicio) / 86400);
if($cuenta_atras <= 0){
echo ('La cuenta regresiva termino');
} else {
echo ('Quedan ' . $cuenta_atras . ' dias');
};
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo @patrick, pero lo estoy tratando de solucionar con `php`, espero no lo tomes a mal!

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta y corregirlo en el lenguaje indicado :)

Answer (score 0):

Una manera simple que se me ocurre es comparar la fecha actual con la fecha tope para sacar los días restantes . te dejo un ejemplo.

```
$dias = dias_restantes('2019/03/28');

echo "Días restantes que quedan: " .$dias;

function dias_restantes($fecha_final) {  
    $fecha_actual = date("Y/m/d");  
    $s = strtotime($fecha_final)-strtotime($fecha_actual);  
    $d = intval($s/86400);  
    $diferencia = $d;  
    return $diferencia;  
}
```

Espero te resulte aclaro que para que el código funcione la manera mas lógica es usar cron para visitar la pagina .